# How to call a function from a subproject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to press a UIButton on my main Xcode project and to run a subproject from my list of projects.
Is this possible ?
Here is my code from `MainViewController` into my Main Project:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func playSubproject(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // here I want to run the SubProject O2App.xcodeproj
        // More exactly I want to run a method from that subproject which is in ViewController.swift and is named startUnity().
    }
}
```

And here is the code from my ViewController subproject:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        backgroundImageView.isHidden = false
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.startUnity()

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleUnityReady), name: NSNotification.Name("UnityReady"), object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleUnityPlayHologram(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("UnityPlayHologram"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AppDelegate from the SubProject where I have the function `startUnity`. I want to call this `startUnity` function into my Main Project if is possible. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var application: UIApplication?

    @objc var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!

    var isUnityRunning = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.application = application
        unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

        currentUnityController = SVFUnityPluginAppController()
        currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // first call to startUnity will do some init stuff, so just call it here and directly stop it again
        startUnity()
        stopUnity()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application)
        }
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
        }
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillEnterForeground(application)
        }
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillTerminate(application)
        }
    }

    public func startUnity() {
        if !isUnityRunning {
            isUnityRunning = true
            currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application!)
        }
    }

    public func stopUnity() {
        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application!)
            isUnityRunning = false
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot with my Main Project and my SubProject:

[image: Structure]

Edit:

In my MainProject I go into Build Settings and in the Header Search Paths I set the path for all my classes from SubProject using this line of code: $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes/Unity" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes/Native" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include". Now in MainViewController I import O2App and now I have access to all that classes. But when I try to call a method from that classes is giving me an error.
This is what I tried to do in the function when I press the button:

```
@IBAction func playSubproject(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ViewController().viewDidLoad()
    }
```

And this is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "type metadata accessor for O2App.ViewController", referenced from:
      RGA_MainProject.MainViewController.playSubproject(__ObjC.UIButton) -> () in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (_not_ images) so they are searchable

Comment: The image is to show to ppl how my structure look. I don't understand what logs you want. I just asked if is possible to press a button and to run a subproject.

Comment: I edit the main post and I added the code from my AppDelegate from the SubProject. There is a method called `startUnity` which I want to call it in the Main Project. How can I do that @AshleyMills ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Your main and subproject both appear to be apps - so how can you expect to call a function in another app?

Comment: In my MainProject I go into Build Settings and in the Header Search Paths I set the path for all my classes from SubProject using this line of code:
$(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes/Unity" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Classes/Native" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/O2App/O2App/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include".

Now in MainViewController I `import O2App` and now I have access to all that classes. But when I try to call a method from that classes is giving me an error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a framework in your subproject. Then you can import this framework in your main project and run code from your subproject. It is the answer for your question.

*FYI. I see that you are dealing with Unity. Good news - it is possible to embed Unity in a framework and in general you are thinking in a right way. Bad news - your implementation has mistakes and is complicated in general. This question can't cover this topic.*

Comment: Split your task at some smaller parts. First of all, check out this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios  to understand how to work with frameworks - create a simple class and get used with frameworks. Then move your complex Unity code to your framework (based on the code provided, I assume that you are able to run Unity inside native iOS application).